# PDF reader for iPad with both bookmarks and continuous scrolling, without long save and load times

Tags: ipad, pdf, books, bookmarks

I'm having trouble finding a good PDF reader for my iPad. Apple's own iBooks app allows adding bookmarks, but doesn't allow continuous scrolling for PDFs, only for EPUBs. This is annoying because most pages are zoomed out past the white margin, so every time I flip a page I need to zoom in past the white margin so the text is bigger.

Adobe reader for iPad doesn't have this problem, since you can easily choose to scroll continuously. However this reader strangely has the fatal flaw of not being able to add bookmarks. This issue has been brought up for years on the official Adobe forums, but it doesn't appear the developers care about adding this feature.

Foxit Reader has both bases covered: it has bookmarks, and it allows continuous scrolling. However, it has annoying save and load times every time I switch to another PDF file.

This is an interesting situation, since for each reader's problem, the other two readers don't have the problem at all; for example, both Adobe and Foxit have continuous scrolling that works wonderfully; both iBooks and Adobe allow instant switching between files, and both ibooks and Foxit allow flawless bookmarks.

Is there a PDF reader for iOS that has all three bases covered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iBooks now has vertical scrolling
It’s enabled via ‘Aa’ at the top right corner

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been a happy [GoodReader](https://www.goodreader.com/) user for many years. Lately, I have switched to [PDF Expert](https://pdfexpert.com/ios), though, since I like its interface better (especially for adding and editing annotations). It is not quite as featureful as GoodReader, though.

Both use tabs to let you switch quickly between documents. I can't comment on the time to open a document compared to the apps you mention, though. Documents generally open quick enough for me.

**Edit:** Oh, wait: GoodReader doesn't do continuous scrolling, it seems. My bad. It's been too long since I used it, I guess.

Comment: yes, I dropped $5 on Goodreader but then realized that it doesn't have continuous scrolling, so that's a no go. I'm using Foxit reader meanwhile; the load times are probably the most bearable of the three.